# I'm having memory issues reading and closing multiple JPG images

Tags: vb.net, image, jpeg, exif, geocode

I'm having memory issues reading and closing multiple JPG images.

---

I'm loading JPG files into an image object, reading the file information (size, dimensions, date, etc.), and reading their EXIF data to get the geocode for Lat/Long.   Then I'm pushing the information to a ListView object.  This is all working great on folders with up to 60 or so JPG's.  Once I go past a certain number (not sure what the threshold actually is) I get my favorite error...

---

************** Exception Text **************
System.OutOfMemoryException: 
Out of memory. at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement)
at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename)

...etc.

---

I'm leaking memory somewhere, but I'm a bit of a novice with .NET applications.  I'm calling this routine from a loop which reads through a collection of JPG files in a directory.

```
Public Function JPGDat(ByRef jpg As FileInfo) As ListViewItem

    Dim filEntry(6) As String
    Dim lstEntry As ListViewItem = Nothing
    Dim pic As Image = Image.FromFile(jpg.FullName) 'HERE IS WHERE WE CRASH

    filEntry(0) = jpg.Name
    filEntry(1) = (Math.Round(jpg.Length / 1024)).ToString()    'File Size
    filEntry(2) = Format(pic.PhysicalDimension.Width, "0")      'Pixel width dimension
    filEntry(3) = Format(pic.PhysicalDimension.Height, "0")     'Pixel height dimension

    Try
        Dim CLatt As Double = GetCoord(pic.GetPropertyItem(2))  'Get Latitude from EXIF
        Dim CLong As Double = GetCoord(pic.GetPropertyItem(4))  'Get Longitude from EXIF

        filEntry(4) = Format(CLatt, "0.000000000000000")
        filEntry(5) = Format(CLong, "0.000000000000000")
    Catch ex As Exception
        filEntry(4) = ""
        filEntry(5) = ""
    End Try
    filEntry(6) = "Date: " + Format(jpg.CreationTime, "yyyy-MM-dd")

    lstEntry = New ListViewItem(filEntry)
    If filEntry(4) <> "" Then
        lstEntry.Checked = True
    End If
    pic.Dispose()

    Return lstEntry
End Function
```

Comment: What memory does Task Manager report your process is using just before it crashes?

Comment: Just because that is where the OOM exception occurs, doesn't mean that is where the issue is. You will need to profile your application to find the leak.

Comment: My apologies folks.  The error was in a corrupt JPG file... not the code.  Adding one more Try command solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put the open JPG command in a Try structure...

```
    Try
        pic = Image.FromFile(jpg.FullName)
        filEntry(2) = Format(pic.PhysicalDimension.Width, "0")      'Pixel width dimension
        filEntry(3) = Format(pic.PhysicalDimension.Height, "0")     'Pixel height dimension

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error in file " + jpg.FullName + vbCrLf + ex.Message)
        JPGDat = New ListViewItem(filEntry)

        Exit Function
    End Try
```

That way, if you get a corrupt JPG, you won't think you have a memory leak!